# Let G be a group, and let f(x)=x^(-1) for all x in G. Is f a function from G to G? If so, is it 1-1, onto?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a group, and let f(x)=x^(-1) for all x in G. Is f a function from G to G? If so, is it 1-1, onto?

Abstract algeba..

I know what it means to be 1-1 and onto..

1-1: f(a)=f(b)=>a=b 
onto: there exists an x for every y.

Comment: It is automorphism.

Comment: Have you applied the definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Is $f$ a function from $G$ to $G$?
```

Yes, note that for each $x\in G, x^{-1}$ is also an element in $G$.

```
If the function one-to-one?
```

If $f(g) = f(h)$ then $g^{-1} = h^{-1}$, so ...

```
If $f$ onto?
```

Given $g\in G$ can you find an element $h\in G$ such that $f(h) = h^{-1} = g$? How would you pick such an $h$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Every $g\in G$ has a unique inverse $g^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the function $f$ has an inverse, because $(x^{-1})^{-1}=\dots$
What functions have an inverse?